# Android Workaround for non-working sensors when screen is off

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

[Edit: Removed all mention of Android version - the issue is present on all versions of android]

Background: When the screen is off, many Android phones do not provide updates to applications of Accelerometer readings by calling onSensorChanged() when the screen is off. This behavior is discussed on S.O. and is further documented here
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708

On some phones (Nexus S, Droid X2, ...) accelerometer values are only provided when there is a significant change in value. Sitting still on a table, for example, there might be one or zero updates per minute

In order to produce code that is robust across phone models, how am I to distinguish between a lack of update events per screen off, vs. lack of updates per non-movement? Should I maintain a database of phone models?

Comment: A good application actually unregister the accelerometer when the activity goes into background.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. An example of a legitimate need for the answer to this question might be a pedometer app that registers the listener in a service.

Comment: My experience has been that a partial wake lock keeps the cpu active even when the screen goes off. If there is no significant change in the accelerometer readings why would you care about an update? I doubt this though, most of the sensor packages give off so much noise that they never read zero.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! On 2.3+, the fact that there is no sensor update in fact appears to imply there is no change - I do not need these updates. On older phones/versions, however, there is no such implication. Therefore the logic required to distinguish "no movement" from "no information" requires me to switch on the phone type/android version. I am very uncomfortable with this, especially given the fact that the behavior of the sensors seem to be known empirically, and not stated in any official looking doc.

Comment: @ldistic Also, your experience with partial wake lock is shared by me, and it appears with S.O. at large with android versions 2.3+. However, pre 2.3, this behavior is only present on some phones. A means by which I could confidently rely on the partial wake lock solution to work always post 2.3+ would by itself be very useful! I have so far only found very empirical sources of information about this.

Comment: I faced the same problem. In my Samsung Galaxy Mini I had Android 2.2 before and my app worked well. Now I upgraded to 2.3 and the accelerometer doesn't work anymore in standby mode. Sometimes it seems that the accelerometer (or my app) saves the latest readings from the sensor and passes them forward continuously when the screen goes off.

Comment: Also it strongly seems that this works on Android 4.0.1 though.

Comment: I managed to keep the accelerometer working by preventing the screen to go off, but instead stay on, but dimmed. I know this is not good solution at all, as it's pretty much blocking one android's main functionality. Also the touch screen isn't locked, if the screen is not turned off or dimmed manually by pressing the power button. From what I've found on internet, I think all we can pretty much do is to wait for google to fix this bug on further OS versions. This should have been fixed on android 2.3 already, but seems that the bug still exists on some phones.

Answer (score 0):

This will be hard to detect.  Android's API provides a way to control the Wake Lock.  But manufacturers have done a TERRIBLE job of implementing this into the OS on their side.  Just TERRIBLE.  You would need to grab a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to keep the phones CPU running when the screen is turned off.

However not all devices use this and will not respond - some half/half respond - and some respond great.

After reading the comments above I can tell you the majority of devices with 2.3+ I have used still do not implement the partial wake lock still.

I personally would not rely on something the manufacturer controls because the market is SO fragmented.  I would try to find a way to get the functionality I'm looking for with a different solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution for this problem for two days now. But still didn't find anything useful.

At this post [here](https://sites.google.com/a/bug-br.org.br/android/technical-documents/sensors-and-standby-mode), by Bruno Albuquerque there's something that could help with motorola phones but it's not generic.

I believe @jjNford is right about manufactures have a finger on that, can you post any info about that?

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708) is a bug report about that dated from 2009