# Constantly monitor accelerometer sensor on Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I need to have a service which constantly monitors the accelerometer sensor. I know that in the past it was not possible to do so without preventing the display from turning off, which is of course awful for battery life.

My question is - is there a good way to implement power efficient accelerometer monitor which would constantly run in the background?

Answer (score 1):

have your Service implement [SensorEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html). Then register your Service to the [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

I checked the docs about sensors for you and I believe the header for [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getSensorList%28int%29) answers your questions. Every issue you have brought up was addressed in the second paragraph.

Comment: And what would be the effect on battery life of having such a service running all the time?

Comment: A service runs until killed, phone lock does not effect this. Services do not directly have an effect on battery. The processing you do with the service does. Receiving the sensor values should be negligible.

Comment: The question is not about the service, but rather about the sensor. I read that the sensor stops working once the phone is locked. And the service can have a negative effect on the battery life if it somehow keeps the CPU running

Comment: @Demiurg, Personally, I don't know if the sensor turns off with the phone, but It sounds like a pile of crap (see my edit). As for the Service having a negative effect on the battery, the impact will be negligible **if** you follow the rules of using sensors as posted in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the accelerometer when the screen is off reliably across all phones. It works for *some* phones, but not others. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11028 for an open bug report.

Also, this question is a duplicate of [Android Workaround for non-working sensors when screen is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769780/android-workaround-for-non-working-sensors-when-screen-is-off)